# Discord.js read the thumbail of an embed

Tags: discord.js, embed

I am trying to do an optimised bumping-reminder for my bot and I wanna do that with reading the thumbail of an embed. I tried this code and more but I dont get it to work. I read the docs but they didnt help
Code:

```
    message.channel.send("okay")
    if (message.embeds[0].thumbnail.url === "https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/-N8TZVFTnkSYClu_Kbvb8KXNn2TvUgyUwLyBYkC7VGg/https/disboard.org/images/bot-command-image-thumbnail-error.png") {
      message.channel.send("embed")
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the URL, first of all? Also what error do you get?

Comment: Okay so, I logged the URL and saw, thats its a different one, thanks for your Tipp. I actually didnt got any Errors, but thanks for the help! :D